# Webpack 4 + Material-UI: How minification of JSS works in Production Mode?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, jss

I am working on a project using **Webpack 4.10.2** and **Material-UI v1.1.0**. [MUI docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#class-names) is talking about class name generator, and I am OK with the result of shortening classes names, but there is something I don't understand in the build process, I am probably missing a Webpack Module or Plugin (I am for instance just using babel-loader and no Plugin).
I just tryed many combinations with **UglifyJsPlugin** (through optimization.minimizer) **compress** and **mangle** but nothing works.

The problem:

The class names injected in the document style tags are shortened, but not the corresponding classes in the body:

### Development mode

Everything is fine when build my project in Development mode, using `webpack -d`:

```
<style type="text/css" data-jss="" data-meta="LayoutNavBar">
    .LayoutNavBar-flex-4 {
      flex: 1;
    }
</style>
```

and in the body, the corresponding classes

```
<h2 class="LayoutNavBar-flex-4">Title</h2>
```

### Production mode

**Styles are broken** when I build in Production mode, I have **inline style with shortened class names** (that's good):

```
<style type="text/css" data-jss="" data-meta="LayoutNavBar">
    .jss4 {
      flex: 1;
    }
</style>
```

but **in the body**, CSS classes are still with their **long names**:

```
<h2 class="LayoutNavBar-flex-4">Title</h2>
```

instead of having:

```
<h2 class="jss4">Title</h2>
```

What am I missing to make it work ? Thanks

Comment: Based on this https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/master/src/utils/createGenerateClassName.js it may be necessary to define the NODE_ENV var. Pretty sure -d and -p don’t set NODE_ENV. On mobile so hard to confirm. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/

Comment: Thanks jens ! that solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case I was excluding `node_modules` from the server bundle, therefore Webpack wouldn't replace `process.env.NODE_ENV` in the module files, while in my client bundle, where `node_modules` were included, it did. So to also minify CSS on the server you will either need to include `node_modules` in the bundle or set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable in the command line session you run the server bundle from.

The best (platform-agnostic) way I could find is to run "npm start --production", or add it as a script in `package.json`. This will automatically set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable of the node session run by the script to `production`.